# How to invalidate that which column having data type mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with some records in one user and another table with empty records. I want to migrate the data of that table from one ***user*** to ***another*** but I got one error **ORA: 01722** because the datatype of the target table is slightly mismatch. What should I do resolve this problem without changes the datatype.
Data type of the source table is-

[image: Description of Source Table]

Description of the target table-

[image: Description of Target Table]

In both table in different user only one column is mismatch datatype ***LOTFRONTAGE***. In source table datatype is **varchar2** and in target table datatype is **Number**.

How to **invalidate** that which column having data type **mismatch**.

Comment: which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into md.house(ID,MSSUBCLASS,MSZONING,
                     LOTFRONTAGE ,LOTAREA,LOTSHAPE,LOTCONFIG,
                     NEIGHBORHOOD,CONDITION1,BLDGTYPE,OVERALLQUAL,
                     YEARBUILT,ROOFSTYLE,EXTERIOR1ST,MASVNRAREA)
 select ID,MSSUBCLASS,MSZONING
 --hier
       ,TO_NUMBER(LOTFRONTAGE),

        LOTAREA,LOTSHAPE,LOTCONFIG,NEIGHBORHOOD,CONDITION1,
        BLDGTYPE,OVERALLQUAL,YEARBUILT,ROOFSTYLE,
        EXTERIOR1ST,MASVNRAREA 
  from SYS.HOUSE_DATA;
```

Comment: This one already used but not run, got an error. I want that how we can invalidate that which column having datatype mismatch

Comment: and what kind of error do u get, i mean when you run the code i gave you

Comment: ORA:01722 Invalid Number

Comment: i think u ve cahracters like +,/,# in  the LOTFRONTAGE field from SYS.HOUSE_DATA . i would check the table definition of  md.house  by tranforming the LOTFRONTAGE  to varchar2 like in SYS.HOUSE_DATA.

Comment: OR try to filter the Data from  SYS.HOUSE_DATA from  invalid data set

Answer (score 0):

> How to invalidate that which column having data type mismatch.

What do you mean by invalidating a column?. There is no such facility available to you in Oracle.

All you can do is to try to identify the non-numeric characters in your `LOTFRONTAGE` . Run this query to find what values are non-numeric.

```
SELECT 
        ID, 
        LOTFRONTAGE 
FROM 
        yoursourcetable
WHERE   REGEXP_LIKE(LOTFRONTAGE, '[^0-9]+');
```

Once you get the ids and column values, you can update those values or replace them in your insert.

```
update yoursourcetable SET LOTFRONTAGE = <numeric_value> 
where ID = <id> and  LOTFRONTAGE = '<non-numeric value>;
```

and run `INSERT`.

**OR**

```
INSERT INTO yourdesttable 
        (col1,col2... 
        ) 
SELECT ID, REPLACE (LOTFRONTAGE ,<non-numeric>,<numeric>),... from yoursourcetable ;
```